# React Native with Expo , Firebase Google Auth. signInWithPopup is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-oauth

I'm trying to setup login via Firebase Auth. By logging in with username and password it works fine but when I call the method to login with google I get the following error:

```
 LOG  [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
```

Firebase Config (Firebase SDK v9.22.1)

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth,GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
//import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(app);
```

login.js

```
import { View, TextInput, Text, FlatList, Pressable,Image,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import {styles} from "../utils/styles";
import { useState } from "react";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword,signInWithPopup} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth, provider} from "../firebase";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
   const [password, setPassword] = useState();
   
   const navigation = useNavigation();
   
   const handleSignIn = async() => {
    try {
        const log = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username, password)
          navigation.navigate("Home", {username: log._tokenResponse.email});
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
       
    }
    const handleGoogleSignIn = async() => {
        try{
            const log = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            console.log(log)
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
  
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.loginscreen}>
        <View style={styles.loginscreen}>
            <View style={styles.logininputContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.loginheading}>Login</Text>
                <TextInput
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    placeholder='Enter your username'
                    style={styles.logininput}
                    onChangeText={(value) => setUsername(value)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.logininputContainer}>

                <TextInput
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    placeholder='Enter your password'
                    style={styles.logininput}
                    onChangeText={(value) => setPassword(value)}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
            </View>
            <Pressable onPress={handleSignIn} style={styles.loginbutton}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.loginbuttonText}>Get Started</Text>
                </View>
            </Pressable>

        </View>
        <Pressable onPress={handleGoogleSignIn} style={styles.googleButton}>
      <Image
       style={styles.googleIcon}
       source={{
        uri: "https://i.ibb.co/j82DCcR/search.png",
       }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.googleButtonText}>Sign in with Google</Text>
     </Pressable>


    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

I just did exactly what is in documentation. I have enabled all of them in Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

im fighting the same issue and im trying to still figure out the solution but this error is tied to "signInWithPopup".

"This happens because the Firebase Javascript SDK is designed for web applications and the signInWithPopup method expects the app to run in a browser. Frog! We will need to find another way to do it." -Carles Capellas

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/apple-google-authentication-in-expo-apps-using-firebase-997125440032

The link above is pretty helpful but not entirely relevant now as it was over 2 years ago